# No “c” wire terminal on my furnace

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

My furnace doesn’t seem to have a “c” terminal I can hook up my adapter to for the nest smart thermostat.

My terminals are numbered instead of lettered. I tried them both but the thermostat still had an error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the diagram of your thermostat?

Comment: What make and model is your furnace, and can you post photos of the wiring diagram that comes with it?

Comment: I posted the wiring diagram, it also has the make and model of that helps. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Try terminal 2

According to the manual for the matching [T8635 thermostat](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf7/142/14152/1415120-honeywell/t8635l.pdf?b8064eedde5ff3e360c0fc86f50b9298), terminals 2 and 3 are the power terminals; since terminal 3 is paired with the thermostat T input on your burner control and thus roughly equivalent to a R terminal, terminal 2 should be usable as a C wire.

Comment: Ok, I’m going to try that this weekend. I’ll let you know how it goes